# comment_reply_link not work with me

Tags: comments

I have this code that get me last comments in my site :

```
function bg_recent_comments($no_comments = 30, $comment_len = 80, $avatar_size = 48) {
                        $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query();
                        $comments = $comments_query->query( array( 'number' => $no_comments , 'status' => 'approve') );
                        $comm = '';
                        if ( $comments ) : foreach ( $comments as $comment ) :
                            $comm .= '<li id="comment-160546">
                            <br><a href="'.get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID).'" style="font-family:droid arabic kufi;text-align: center;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;">'.get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID).'</a><br><br>
                                <div class="comment byuser comment-author-hasan-ly odd alt thread-odd thread-alt depth-1 comment-wrap">
                                    <div class="comment-avatar">'.get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, $avatar_size ).'</div>
                                    <div class="comment-content">
                                        <div class="author-comment">
                                            <cite class="fn">'.get_comment_author( $comment->comment_ID ).'</cite>                  
                                            <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="' . get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID . '">Post URL</a></div><!-- .comment-meta .commentmetadata -->
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- #comment-##  --><br>
                            </li>';
                        endforeach; else :
                            $comm .= 'No comments.';
                        endif;
                        echo $comm; 
                    }
```

Now my problem is when add `comment_reply_link` to can any user replay to this comment. its now show the form reply,

When var_dump `comment_reply_link` its return me NULL.

How can solve it

Answer (score 0):

The function `comment_reply_link` echos the function `get_comment_reply_link`. If you look at the [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_reply_link/#source-code) you see, that up to 3 arguments are needed for a proper functionality.

1. **`$args`** an array of optional arguments that overwrite the default values
2. **`$comment`** an optional `comment_id` or WP_Comment object the comment should reply to.
3. **`$post`** an optional `post_id` or WP_Post object where the comment is going to be displayed on.

If the function returns `null`, it cannot figure out the relating `$post`. Try to add this parameter to your function call, e.g. `comment_reply_link(null, null, $post_id)` or `$comm.= get_comment_reply_link(null, $comment);` (within your foreach loop).

If the function returns `false`, comments are disabled for this post.

Source: [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_reply_link/)